# Can a motherboard support more GPUs than its total PCI-e slots?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

Suppose your typical ATX motherboard (or similar) has X number of PCI-e slots. Is it possible to connect additional GPUs (or any PCI-e device for that matter) beyond X?

I've seen a few solutions, however there's always some sort of 'but'. PCI-e backplanes require a special host board and become costly. External cards connected via a dock simply use an existing PCI-e slot anyway and don't actually increase capacity.

Basically, is there a way to split the PCI-e slots/lanes. If a x16 device can work as x1, is it possible to use the rest of the idle lanes for additional devices? In a gross oversimplification, an analogy would be like a USB hub.

In my particular case, I'm trying to get about 10 GPUs on flexible risers for farming purposes, so bandwidth and spacing isn't an issue.

Comment: Are you asking if you can connect more PCI-E devices to a motherboard that exceed the number of PCI-E that motherboard has?  "is there a way to split the PCI-e slots/lanes" - Nope.  "If a x16 device can work as x1, is it possible to use the rest of the idle lanes for additional devices?" - This is based on the design of the motherboard and the CPU.  "a gross oversimplification, an analogy would be like a USB hub." A PCI-E hub does not exist.

Comment: In that case, would there be any way to have a single system that can support a large number of GPUs? The most I've seen on a motherboard is 8

Comment: Unless you are going to design your motherboard, or wait until somebody does, I don't see that happening.  [AMD is pushing for technology adoption that might help though.](http://techfrag.com/2016/03/16/new-razer-blade-gaming-laptop-allows-external-gpu-support/)

Comment: Still looking around for solutions. I came across this, which appears to be some sort of splitter. Thoughts? http://amfeltec.com/products/flexible-x4-pci-express-4-way-splitter-gpu-oriented/